# How can I run IRT-RSM on categorical items for measures of noncognitive skills if for some levels for some items there are 0 observations?

Tags: categorical-data, stata, categorical-encoding, item-response-theory

I am working on data with psychosocial scales in Stata. There are five measures of psychosocial ability used in the data, with between 4 to 9 items for each. All the items are measured on 4-pt Likert scales. For some of the items, entries for extreme values on the Likert scale are missing. Eg. Agency scale - Item no. 2 - No one in the data set chooses "Strongly Disagree" therefore, there are no entries for "1" on the Likert scale for the second item on the Agency Scale.
When I run the "irt rsm AG1 AG2 AG3 AG4" command, the following prompt comes up "items AG1 AG2 AG3 AG4 must have the same number of levels".
How can I still run the IRT RSM for such data?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. Questions solely about how software works are [off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, but you may have a real statistical question buried here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you understand the statistical concepts involved, the software-specific elements are self-evident or at least easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: The title is looking good now.